# Recognizing algebraic independence among Schur polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-functions

Given a set of integer partitions $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\dots \lambda_n\}$. Are there combinatorial criteria for deciding whether the associated Schur polynomials $s_{\lambda_1}, s_{\lambda_2},\dots s_{\lambda_n}$ are algebraically independent?

If this is too hard, are there any surprising necessary or sufficient criteria?

Comment: Are you interested in algebraic relations among Schur functions like: https://doi.org/10.37236/1560 (see Theorem 2)? So, this gives a pattern needed to be avoided for algebraic independence. If useful I could make an answer outlining the main theorem so the paper doesn't have to opened to see what's inside.

Comment: @JohnMachacek That's an interesting relation. I wonder if it is the case that all algebraic relations are built out of such identities (and Giambelli type formulas etc.). I think it's useful to have an answer with partial progress of the form "patterns to avoid".

Comment: Somewhat related blog post: https://realopacblog.wordpress.com/2019/09/22/the-schur-cone-and-the-cone-of-log-concavity/

Answer (score 4):

I'll add further details to my comment and make it an answer. This will give algebraic relations between certain collections of six Schur polynomials. Hence, for algebraic independence it will give a necessary condition of avoiding these six Schur polynomials together. This relation comes from [Bijective proofs for Schur function identities which imply Dodgson's condensation formula and Plücker relations](https://doi.org/10.37236/1560) by Fulmek and Kleber (see Theorem 2 of this paper). I will change notation from the linked paper to agree with the notation in the question. Take $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq a_{r+1}$ if we let
$$\lambda_1 = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_r)$$
$$\lambda_2 = (a_2, a_2, \dots, a_{r+1})$$
$$\lambda_3 = (a_2, a_3, \dots, a_r)$$
$$\lambda_4 = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{r+1})$$
$$\lambda_3 = (a_2-1, a_3-1, \dots, a_{r+1}-1)$$
$$\lambda_4 = (a_1+1, a_2+1, \dots, a_r+1)$$
then
$$s_{\lambda_1}s_{\lambda_2} = s_{\lambda_3}s_{\lambda_4} + s_{\lambda_5}s_{\lambda_6}.$$
Letting $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \cdots = \lambda_{r+1} = c$ we find that $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = (c)^r$, $\lambda_3 = (c)^{r-1}$, $\lambda_4 = (c)^{r+1}$, $\lambda_5 = (c-1)^r$, and $\lambda_6 = (c+1)^r$ which are all rectangle shapes recovering a result of Kirillov (which is cited in the linked paper).

Comment: See also "Planar flows and quadratic relations over semirings" by Danilov, Karzanov, and Koshevoy: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2578.

Comment: And a somewhat related conjecture of Lam, Postnikov, and Pylyavskyy is discussed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608134.