# An identity for Schur polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, determinants, enumerative-combinatorics

Given a partition $\lambda$, the *Schur polynomials* can be defined, among many other ways, as
$$S_{\lambda}(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_a)=\frac{\det\left(\xi_i^{\lambda_j+a-j}\right)_{i,j=1}^a}{\det\left(\xi_i^{a-j}\right)_{i,j=1}^a}.$$
Let $(n^c)=(n,\dots,n)\vdash cn$ be a short-hand notation. Now, define the polynomials
$$\Psi(n^c,a):=s_{(n^c)}(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_a).$$

I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Assume $0<c\leq a$. Is this identity true?
> \begin{align*}
> \Psi(n^c,a)\cdot\Psi((n-2)^c,a+1)
> &=\Psi((n-1)^c,a)\cdot \Psi((n-1)^c,a+1) \\
> &-\Psi((n-1)^{c-1},a)\cdot \Psi((n-1)^{c+1},a+1).
> \end{align*}

Comment: in any case I would use notation $c=a-b>0$ instead of $b$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: done. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly also $c\leqslant a$ is important. In the definition of $S_\lambda$, what is $n$ and how is it related to $a$?

Comment: Now, I see both comments are valid, Fedor.

Comment: This is a special case of this identity https://mathoverflow.net/a/379118/2384

Comment: A relevant paper is https://www.emis.de/journals/JACO/Volume13_2/g5r4h1nv603p465m.fulltext.pdf.